# I'm working on an e-commerce project with typescript and sanity.io, and i am getting an error

Tags: typescript, sanity

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_ref').

when trying to use the code to display the content of the API on the webpage. what seems to be the issue and how can I come to a resolve to successfully display the contents on the webpage?

```
const showProducts = (category: number) => {
    return products.filter((product) => product.category._ref === categories[category]._id).map((product) => <Product product={product} key={product._id}/>);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you what the issue is. In the filter(), the value of product.category is undefined at some point.
Check the values by logging product in the first line of the function & you'll get the reason